# Add data to Parse.com class by sending email

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm working on a website where there's a requirement for pretty constant updates, adding names to a list of backers. Naturally, as a developer who has other work, I don't want to be responsible for updating it all the time.

Since we're using Angular, there's no frontend web portal, so I thought of Parse.com as an easy way for the client to log in and add names as entries under the correct class. Works fine. But the client finds it too hard to use, so I'm looking for another solution. A thought I had was email, so I'm going for it.

**How can I add a new entry in a Parse DB in response to an email sent to a specific address?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Didn't do enough Googling. Easiest way to do it seems to set up an account at [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) and set up a Route to forward certain data to a cloud function in Parse. Who knew. [More details.](https://www.parse.com/questions/is-it-possible-for-a-parse-app-to-receive-emails-from-user-analyze-data-then-store)

Comment: sometimes the act of typing out the question in a structured manner helps in finding the solution. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging